# How to connect soft bricked tablet to pc without USB debugging enabled

Tags: adb, samsung, unbricking, connection-issues, usb-debugging

I tried rooting my Galaxy tab a 9.7 using Odin and soft bricked it. I went into system recovery mode and clicked wipe data/factory reset thinking it would reset back to stock. My tablet is still bricked and usb debugging got turned off so now I can't connect to pc to install the original firmware. Is there anything I can do to connect my tablet to my PC so I can reset my device? Can I use ADB to turn USB debugging back on? I can still get to Odin mode and recovery mode on my tablet. My main problem is connecting my tablet to my PC. Thank you.

Comment: "My tablet is still bricked and usb debugging got turned off so now I can't connect to pc to install the original firmware" - Odin is what you should use to flash the factory firmware.

Comment: I can't connect to Odin because USB debugging is disabled :(

Comment: Odin connectivity should by no means be related to USB debugging. Just boot to download mode with the key combo and start doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

These firmwares are for the Galaxy Tab A 9.7 Wifi and are mirrored for faster download speeds. This is also an pit file collection incase of any person who has messed up their partitions.

What Do These UnBrick Firmwares Do?
Basically, if you ever have an soft-brick or any sort, these firmwares will help get out of that. What makes these different from the rest for say like sammobile or samsung-updates is that these are separated into different tars which the SamFirm Tool provides an option to include binary nature aka PIT and separate tars like Bootloader, AP, CSC and so on. These should help you unbrick your Tab A in most cases and even somewhat worst ones. IF you are in an minor bootloop and just need to get back to stock, use sammobile and download the firmwares from there. Those are the regular ones. You can still use these if your doing the same also but these can help in desperate situations.

How To Use/Flash These Firmwares?!
Simply just download the one for your Tab A model and in the zip it contains different tars. Place the tars in the appropriate sections in odin. Example: Put the AP bla bla bla Tar in the AP Tab Of Odin and the BL tar in the BL tab in odin.
In most cases for say like you flashed a bad rom or in a bootloop, you will only need to flash the AP and BL Tars Only. Most times you dont need to flash CSC. Flash the CSC Tar if your Tab A is not booting up after flashing BL and AP Tars. Make SURE YOU GIVE IT 30 Minutes after flashing in odin if it doesnt seem to boot.

Firmware Downloads (Fast Servers):
SM-T550 Tab A 9.7 Inch
Version: T550XXU1AOF5/T550XAR1AOF5/T550XXU1AOF5/T550XXU1AOF5 
Region: XAR [USA]
Download: https://mega.nz/#!usxzTJTI!r9vhUbTO_...dhqSanCI00sZOU

ODIN DOWNLOAD: 
Odin 3.09 Download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/028kidvc9q...v3.09.zip?dl=0

Source: [xda-developers.com](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-a/help/sm-t550-unbrick-firmware-pit-collection-t3148046)

Comment: I can't connect to Odin because USB debugging is disabled.

Answer (score -3):

No you cannot use adb but most phones do have a com port open where you can push factory OTA images through.

Comment: -1: please avoid generic answers. Since the phone model was provided, you should be able to offer more in-depth guidance.

Comment: Okay will do from now on

Comment: You may find a bunch of critiques on your answers. I look forward to your improved answers, and have faith you'll wisely use those critiques to write said answers. Welcome to Android SE, by the way.

Comment: I have a tablet and haven't noticed any com ports. Maybe they have one inside the tablet but my GF and I had a hard time opening the tablet last night.

Comment: Com port will be routed through USB